# Java ResultSet returning all records after the first correct record is found from MySQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, database, sorting, resultset

Ok, so for example my table would look like:

```
┌──────┬────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│UserID│Username│CurrentLeague│TotalPoints│
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│1     │Elliot  │randomLeague │15         │
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│2     │Callum  │randomLeague │20         │
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│3     │Rory    │testLeague   │17         │
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│4     │Admin   │NULL         │0          │
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│5     │Steve   │randomLeague │21         │
└──────┴────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘
```

And here is my code in my Java project for the class that I'm using here.

```
public int getLeaguePosition(String username)
{
    try
    {
        int leaguePosition = 0;
        String leagueName = getLeague(username);
        System.out.println("League Name: " + leagueName);
        ArrayList<SortingUser> sortingUser = new ArrayList<SortingUser>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CurrentLeague = ?";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, leagueName);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            String retrievedUsername = resultSet.getString("Username");
            System.out.println(retrievedUsername);
            SortingUser retrievedUser = new SortingUser(retrievedUsername);
            sortingUser.add(retrievedUser);
        }
        Collections.sort(sortingUser);
        for(int i = 0; i < sortingUser.size(); i++)
        {
            SortingUser retrievedSortingUser = sortingUser.get(i);
            String retrievedUsername = retrievedSortingUser.getUsername();
            if(retrievedUsername.contains(username) && username.contains(retrievedUsername))
            {
                leaguePosition = i + 1;
                System.out.println("League Position for " + username.toUpperCase() + " is " + leaguePosition);
                return leaguePosition;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get league position for: " + username);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and if I gave it "Rory" as the username it would return the records with ID 3, 4 and 5 rather than just 3 when calculating the position.

Why does it do this? I'm fairly sure my code is correct because when I copy that exact SQL query into phpMyAdmin it works perfectly.

Comment: You return the first matching league position, what are you asking here? By the way `leaguePosition = i + 1;` looks wrong to me.

Comment: What do you mean by " if i gave it 'Rory' as the username"? Your code doesn't ask for a user name. It's prompting for a league name, and your SQL query is querying by league name.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah thats because arrays start at 0 and the position's of things in a table start at 1. for example the first column would be read as column 0 instead of column 1. :)

Comment: @Kenster The function takes a username as a parameter. 

    public int getLeaguePosition(String username)

and then the function works out what league their in and then returns their league position!

Comment: @Elliot Don't use an external rowid as a column!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Maybe I should add clarification. This function is a part of a Football League system. Where if you are top of the table you may be in row 0 but your position isnt 0th, its 1st. thats why I added 1 onto that. Trust me thats not the issue haha :)

Comment: What is `SortingUser`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic `SortingUser` is a class that I've made that literally just stores the returned users from the query. It's there so that I can sort an array of names based off of their affiliated scores. rather than just sorting the names alphabetically or sorting the scores with no usernames attatched numerically. I leant about the concept from this tutorial... [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/) :)

Comment: But you only pass the user name to the `SortingUser` object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you were trying to do there with the SortingUser, but I'd go with much simpler code, and **let SQL do its own sorting**. It's usually very efficient at that, especially if you have the proper indexes on the table.

```
public int getLeaguePosition(String username)
{
    try
    {
        String leagueName = getLeague(username);
        System.out.println("League Name: " + leagueName);

        // This is returning all the users in the same league sorted by descending points.

        String query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CurrentLeague = ? ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, leagueName);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        int leaguePosition = 0;
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            // Since the result set is already sorted, the first player has the most points, so his
            // leaguePosition is one. The second has the next best number of points, so his position
            // is two, and so on. So we keep the leaguePosition var based on the number of the row.

            leaguePosition++;

            // And if the user name retrieved actually matches the one that we passed, then this is
            // his league position.

            String retrievedUsername = resultSet.getString("Username");
            if ( retrievedUsername.equals( username ) ) {
                break;
            }

        }
        resultSet.close();

        return leaguePosition;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get league position for: " + username);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I didn't realise that SQL could sort things. That makes things a lot easier. Still don't understand why my method didn't work. But oh well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well, you didn't include the code for SortingUser, so we can't say if your sorting was correct or not. As a rule, when showing code, you have to show all the code that's called by that code as well (except things that are in standard libraries, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in **SortingUser** class?

Collections.sort() will not sort the objects, if you haven't implemented Comparable in your class.

for simple example check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) out!!

Comment: Yes that's literally all the sorting user class has in it, well that and a few getters and the constructor haha. But dw @RealSkeptic fixed my issue :)